# Exclusionary Cart Price Rule - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to set up a exclusionary shopping cart price rule in Magento 2 using a coupon code.

e.g. Apply a 10% discount to all products on the store with X coupon code, but NOT to the following Manufacturer's.

**I have the following selected in Actions:**

Apply: Percent of product price discount

Discount Amount: 10

Maximum Qty Discount is applied to: 1

Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 1

Apply to Shipping Amount: Disabled (No)

Discard subsequent rules: Enabled (Yes)

**The conditional logic that I have created is as follows:**
[image]
Nothing too complicated, I would think. Eventually, there will be multiple Manufacturers for this rule, but I've scaled it back to a single manufacturer to diagnose the issue.

What I have found is that it is correctly **NOT** applying the discount on 'some' of the products in the manufacturer range.

[image]

On other products in the same manufacturer range it is still allowing the discount to be applied for some reason?

[image]

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Is the blue variation set with Delkim manufacturer ?

Comment: @LeandroRitter, yes all colour variations are part of the Manufacturer. :-)